# Dynamic MenuItem in UiBinder (Permission Based)

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwtp

I have the scenario where I need to display Menuitem based user roles.

Can I achieve this by uiBinder or I need to do it in java, I know UiBinders are not for rendering and only declarative, But, Is there any ways that I could achieve this.

I have used UiBinders all over, So I am trying not to do any java code for widgets.

Thanks,
Bennet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid some of the logic to will have to be written in Java. You'll be able to wire most of the UI layout in the UiBinder. However, choosing how the display changes depending on the user's role will require Java. I think pseudo-code like this

```
if(currentUser.isAdmin()) {
    menu.setRoleLabel("admin");
} else {
    menu.setRoleLabel("standar user")
}
```

cannot be handled through UiBinder. You'll have to roll your own Java logic to change the UI's state.